# SpringBoot maven build war using specific application.properties

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with has three `application.properties` files :

1. application.properties
2. application-qa.properties
3. application-prod.properties

I want build a war using maven by using one of the properties depending on the environment the application with be deployed too i.e `dev`, `qa` or `prod`.

How can I do this. I'm pretty new to Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable will activate the intended profile. for example, in order to activate the `qa` profile, set the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable to `qa`. Read more about profile specific properties [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) in Spring Boot Documentation.

Comment: I have a windows machine and I did set the environment variable SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE to qa. But when I run the application in tomcat it still uses the values from application.properties file ?

Comment: No I right clicked on My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Properties -> Environment Variable. Do I need to set it using set command ?

Comment: I tried to set it using command line also  : setx SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE qa . It still loads values from application.properties :( ?

Comment: I had to restart the computer and now it works. Also is there a way we can build the war using only one of the application.properties, so that we don't have to set the environment variable ?

Comment: Set the `spring.profiles.default` in `application.properties` to your intended profile and then build the project

Comment: You don't want to build a war per environment, as you want to promote the binary that is tested. You don't want to rebuild just because you need to move to a different env. If you do that you would basically have to retest as it is  a new binary...

Comment: Setting the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE env variable worked in this case.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Aproach

On Linux environments

```
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=qa
```

and you can check if it was set on OS with the command:

```
$ env
```

After that you can run:

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

So you'll be able to see this line on startup:

```
2018-05-17 17:33:21.722  INFO 8245 --- [main] 
b.j.t.d.InteropDocumentosApplication     : The following profiles are active: qa
```

**2.** Aproach

via gradle build:

on **application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=@activeProfile@
```

on **build.gradle**

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

processResources {
     filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [ 
             activeProfile: project.property('activeProfile')
     ]
}
```

You can use a property called activeProfile. So you have to supply the **qa** value when you run the build:

```
./gradlew build -PactiveProfile=qa
```