# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline - Build Spring Boot based on specific application.profile

Tags: spring-boot, azure-devops, environment, application.properties

I have a Spring Boot application and I make use of Azure DevOps to automatically build/test the project and deploy the artifact.

My question is as follows: How can I build based on a specific application.profile? Right now it just builds but in my project I have the following 3 files:

- application.properties
- application-test.properties
- application-acceptance.properties

How can I for example build based on "application-test.properties"?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
stages: 
 - stage: Build
displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
 - job: MavenPackageAndPublishArtifacts
displayName: Maven Package and Publish Artifacts
pool:vmImage: $(vmImageName)

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Maven Package'
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to artifact staging directory'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    Contents: '**/target/*.?(war|jar)'
    TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

- upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  artifact: drop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [SpringBoot maven build war using specific application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757363/springboot-maven-build-war-using-specific-application-properties)

> Setting the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable will
>   activate the intended profile. for example, in order to activate the
>   `qa` profile, set the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable to
>   `qa`. Read more about profile specific properties [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) in Spring
>   Boot Documentation.

About how to use environment, you could also take a look at this blog: [Using Environment Variables in Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2019/02/08/using-environment-variables-in-azure-devops-pipelines.aspx)